# get number of fields based on variable

Tags: php, html, pdo, mysqli, phpmyadmin

My insert looks like this:

```
function train_add() {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO train_information "
        . "(train_name, tare_weight, number_of_bogies, number_of_axles, wheel_diameter_min, wheel_diameter_max)"
        . "VALUES (:train_name, :tare_weight, :number_of_bogies, :number_of_axles, :wheel_diameter_min, :wheel_diameter_max) ";
            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindParam(':train_name', $_POST['train_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':tare_weight', $_POST['tare_weight'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':number_of_bogies', $_POST['number_of_bogies'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':number_of_axles', $_POST['number_of_axles'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':wheel_diameter_min', $_POST['wheel_diameter_min'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':wheel_diameter_max', $_POST['wheel_diameter_max'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->execute();    
        }
```

And i insert it via a form:

```
<div id='toevoegen_trein'>
            <form action="add_train_send.php" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Train Name:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="train_name" required><br></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Tare Weight:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="tare_weight" required><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number of Bogies:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="number_of_bogies" required><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number of Axles:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="number_of_axles"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Wheel Diameter Minimal:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="wheel_diameter_min"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Wheel Diameter Maximal:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="wheel_diameter_max"><br></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="toevoegen" value="Next"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
```

add_train_send.php:

```
<?php
    $add_train = $database->train_add();
?>
```

Now. When i press submit on the form, it goes to add_train_send.php.
I want that page not to only sends the information to the Database. But i want to get the number of axles aswell. (and then something like a fill in field behind them).
now i dont know how to do this. Because if the number of axles is 6 i only want the page to create 6 fields. If the number of axles is 12 i want it to create 12 fields.

How do i do this?

EDIT: Here a example of how i want it to look:

[image]

Also in my database, i have a table named: `axle`
with the content:

```
train_id
axle_id
axle
distance
```

it already has a trigger, so when i insert a train with 12 axles, it makes 12 adds 12 axles already, all i need to do is to fill in the distance (See .png example)

Comment: `$database` is a class?

Comment: Yes (message to short haha)

Comment: can you be more specific about question? where you want to create new fields? what fields it should be and what relationship is between those fields and rest of the form, database etc.?

Comment: il make something in mockups. Give me a moment haha

Comment: also, can you give us an example what result should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show **X** amount of textfields(or whatever input type. **X** being the users input on **number of axles**)

To do this you need to get the value of the number of axles which you already have: `$_POST['number_of_axles']`

After that you go through a for loop the **X** amount of times. I've also noticed your number of axles is not required but some other fields are. So you first need to check if `$_POST['number_of_axles']` `isset`. So you start like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['number_of_axles'])){
   for($i=0; $i<$_POST['number_of_axles']; $i++){
      echo "<input type='text' name='axles[$i]'>";
   }
}
```

Now you start the form outside of the for loop and end it outside of the for loop.

**EDIT:**

Also I forgot to mention about the `name` part. I declared the name like so: `name='axles[$i]'` to make sure every textfield has a different name. Now when you check `$_POST['axles']`. You'll get an array somewhat like:

```
[1]=>'input_of_axle1'
[2]=>'input_of_axle2'
[3]=>'input_of_axle3'
```

Now you can just loop through it. Something like this:

```
$axles = $_POST['axles'];

foreach($axles as $axle){
   echo 'This is an axle:'.$axle; // I have no idea what an axle is
}
```

Comment: You forgot to echo that tag. That would be a nice error in log :)

Comment: @JánStibila haha yeah I'll edit it. What a dumb mistake. Thank you

Comment: This is it :) And from that i want it to insert on the table: Axle. But i'm sure i know how to do that haha (I hope)!